# Convert Rows using PIVOT in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to convert rows to columns (Based on different Years) in SQL with pivot function but cannot make it happened. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is the original data and the expected outcome:

[image]

the original data:

```
Type |  Name |  Cost |  Year

A   NDA $385.00 FY22

A   ING $342.00 FY21

A   IEG $360.00 FY21

A   ERT $346.00 FY21

A   OVA $176.00 FY20

A   ZIO $310.00 FY20

A   ZIO $301.00 FY22

A   ZIO $237.00 FY21

A   ZIU $398.00 FY21

A   ZIU $338.00 FY20

A   ZIU $101.00 FY22

B   RLA $319.00 FY22

B   RLA $148.00 FY20

B   RLA $206.00 FY21

B   ACK $224.00 FY22

B   EZA $282.00 FY21

B   EON $187.00 FY21

B   EON $250.00 FY20

B   EGG $297.00 FY20
```

the expected outcome:
[image]

Below is the code I'm using:

```
select Type, Name, sum(price) as Cost, Year

from
(
  select Type, Name, price, Year
  from ProductDB
) a

pivot
(
 ????
) as PivotTable;
```

Comment: You should search "conditional aggregation". That would be how I would tackle this.

Comment: I would, personally, suggest looking at how to use conditional aggregation over the restrictive `PIVOT` operator.

Comment: Thank you all you guys feedbacks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional Aggregations give you a bit more flexibility, but if you are looking for the PIVOT

```
Select *
 From (
       select Type, Name, Cost, Year
        from ProductDB
       ) src
 Pivot ( sum(price) for Year in ( [FY20],[FY21],[FY22] ) ) pvt ;
```

**Note:**  Assuming SUM(Cost)  but you could use MAX(),AVG(), etc.

Conditional Aggregations

```
Select Type
      ,Name
      ,FY20  = sum( case when Year = 'FY20' then Cost end )         -- missing will show NULL
      ,FY21  = sum( case when Year = 'FY21' then Cost else 0 end )  -- missing will show 0
      ,FY22  = sum( case when Year = 'FY22' then Cost else 0 end )
From  ProductDB
Group By Type,Name
```

Comment: It works like a charm!  Thanks you so much John! Can you please show me how to use Conditional Aggregations to implement it?  Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @Ben Sure... give me a moment

Comment: @Ben See updated answer

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is what I use and there's actually no PIVOT clause.

So I can solve this problem using CASE statements like this:

```
SELECT Type, Name, 
SUM(CASE WHEN Year is 'FY20' THEN Cost ELSE 0 END) as FY20,
SUM(CASE WHEN Year IS 'FY21' THEN Cost ELSE 0 END) as FY21,
SUM(CASE WHEN Year is 'FY22' THEN Cost ELSE 0 END) as FY22
FROM original_data
GROUP BY Name;
```

Hope that Helps!